# Unable to launch AVD in Android Studio, VTX is already enabled in BIOS

Tags: android

VT-x is enabled in BIOS, but when I try to install Intel HAXM, it pop ups with the following error:

> "this computer doesn't support vt-x. haxm could not be installed"

So I am unable to launch AVD in Android Studio. Any suggestions why?

System configuration: (Win 8.1 pro, AMD A5 processor, 8GB RAM)

Comment: I fixed the formatting, spelling, and grammar in your question for you. Please spend a little more time in the future to make the question a little tidier future users of the site. Then you are more likely to attract good answers!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an Intel chip and not an AMD, try these steps.

Go to Control Panel → Program and Feature.

Click on Turn Window Features on and off. A window opens.

Uncheck Hyper-V option and restart your system.

Then try the HAXM installation.

Also, if you still have problems, disable your antivirus and try the install again. If it works, then after just re-enable your antivirus software.

Comment: thanks for reply, but i want to clear a few things. my processor is AMD A6, hyper-v feature is already UNCHECKED, and i don't have any anti-virus installed on my system.